# How to find summary statistics for all unique combinations of factors in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data, aggregation, plyr

I want to calculate a summary of a variable in a data.frame for each unique combination of factors in the data.frame. Should I use plyr to do this? I am ok with using loops as opposed to apply() ; so just finding out each unique combination would be enough.

Comment: Question is misleading as you ask about unique combinations of factors and then in details you ask about summary by unique combinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I think `aggregate` is probably the solution you are seeking, if you are want to create an explicit list of all possible factor combinations, `expand.grid` will do that for you. e.g.

```
> expand.grid(height = seq(60, 80, 5), weight = seq(100, 300, 50),
             sex = c("Male","Female"))
       height weight    sex
1      60    100   Male
2      65    100   Male
... 
30     80    100 Female
31     60    150 Female
```

You could then loop over each row in the resulting data frame to pull out records from your original data.

Answer (score 11):

See `aggregate` and `by`. For example, from the help file for `aggregate`:

```
## Compute the averages according to region and the occurrence of more
## than 130 days of frost.
aggregate(state.x77,
      list(Region = state.region,
           Cold = state.x77[,"Frost"] > 130),
      mean)
```

Comment: fastest running correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's the plyr solution, which has the advantage of returning multiple summary stats and producing a progress bar for long computes:

```
library(ez) #for a data set
data(ANT)
cell_stats = ddply(
    .data = ANT #use the ANT data
    , .variables = .(cue,flanker) #uses each combination of cue and flanker
    , .fun = function(x){ #apply this function to each combin. of cue & flanker
        to_return = data.frame(
            , acc = mean(x$acc)
            , mrt = mean(x$rt[x$acc==1])
        )
        return(to_return)
    }
    , .progress = 'text'
)
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked, although I had to drop a comma in the call to data.frame.

    stats = ddply(
    .data = ords
    , .variables = .(Symbol,SysID,Hour) 
    , .fun = function(x){ 
        to_return = data.frame(
             s = sum(x$Profit)
            , m = mean(x$Profit)
        )
        return(to_return)
    }
    , .progress = 'text'
)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other suggestions you may find the `describe.by()` function in the `psych` package useful.
It can be used to show summary statistics on numeric variables across levels of a factor variable.

Answer (score 1):

In [`library(doBy)`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doBy/vignettes/doBy.pdf) there is also the `summaryBy()` function, e.g.

```
summaryBy(DV1 + DV2 ~ Height+Weight+Sex,data=my.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like `cast()`, from the reshape package because of it's simplicity:

```
library(reshape)
cast(melt(tips), sex ~ smoker | variable, c(sd,mean, length))
```